# PyTorch installation with conda 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, installation, pytorch, conda, setup.py

Trying to run `import torch` gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/art/torch/__init__.py", line 246, in <module>
    ''').strip()) from None
ImportError: Failed to load PyTorch C extensions:
    It appears that PyTorch has loaded the `torch/_C` folder
    of the PyTorch repository rather than the C extensions which
    are expected in the `torch._C` namespace. This can occur when
    using the `install` workflow. e.g.
        $ python setup.py install && python -c "import torch"

    This error can generally be solved using the `develop` workflow
        $ python setup.py develop && python -c "import torch"  # This should succeed
    or by running Python from a different directory.
```

Then when I run the new command, I get this:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have tried running the command in different folders and it still fails. My torch folder has no setup.py file when I manually check.

Comment: The second error shows you are running the system Python, not a Conda installation. Please include information on how you are running Python. The first error kind of looks like you have manually downloaded the source of `torch` and are trying to develop on it. That is extremely uncommon and only advanced users would ever attempt this. Maybe you could also clarify the end goal, rather than just the immediate problem.